# Projection onto a dilated set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, projection

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be non-empty, closed and convex. Also let $\delta>0$ and consider the dilated set defined as follows
$$ D_{\delta}(C) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \| x - \pi_{C}(x)\|_2 \le \delta\}, $$
where $\pi_C:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow C$ is the orthogonal projection onto $C$, which is well-defined since $C$ is non-empty, closed and convex. Assuming that I know how to calculate $\pi_C(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I would like to know if it is possible to express $\pi_{D_\delta}$ in terms of $\pi_C$.

Comment: I doubt it unless you have some special characteristics. If you take $x \in D_\delta(C) \setminus C$ then one projection is zero and the other not.

Comment: Oh I see.. Maybe it is possible outside of $D_\delta(C)$ then. In this case both projections $\pi_{D_\delta (C)}(x)$ and $\pi_
C(x)$ are different than $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the dilated set $D$ for simplicity.
Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
If $x\in D$, then $\pi_D(x)=x$.
So assume $x\notin D$. Then the desired projection is
$$\pi_D(x)=\pi_C(x)+\delta\frac{x-\pi_C(x)}{\|x-\pi_C(x)\|}.$$

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! Could you elaborate a little bit? or send me a reference for this particular problem?

Comment: Proposition 29.10 in the book by Bauschke and Combettes. Basically you just check the projection theorem - clearly the point belongs to $D$, and you check that the obtuse angle condition is satisfied.

Comment: thank you again!